# Ipset + Iptables. Правило в iptables производит обход IP в Ipset тогда, когда это не нужно

Tags: iptables, firewall, ipset

Моя конечная цель: заблокировать огромное количество подсетей благодаря Ipset

Я создаю правило в Iptables. И я ожидаю, что ТОЛЬКО пользователи которые подключены с IP адресов начиная с 128.0.0.0 и заканчивая 159.255.255.254 будут проверены через Ipset, в списке под названием "block128", которые содержит все подсети которые я хочу запретить начиная с 128.0.0.0 и заканчивая 159.255.255.254

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 128.0.0.0/3 -m set --match-set block128 src -j DROP
```

Но, например, я подключаюсь с IP адреса 85.133.90.30 которые не попадает под этот список и я появляется задержка в 3-5 секунд (которой быть не должно, ведь я не попадаю под этот 128.0.0.0/3, и по логике меня не должно сверять с списком "block128"), такая же, если бы я например подключался с IP 128.133.90.30. Убирая данное правило - проблема исчезает, задержки нет

Возможно, я что-то делаю не так. И хотел бы узнать, почему так происходит и как сделать правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже проверяются все условия.

Используй jump чтоб убрать эту проверку в отдельную цепь

```
iptables -A INPUT -s ... -j CHEKBLOCK
iptables -A CHEKBLOCK --match .. -j DROP
iptables -A CHEKBLOCK -j RETURN
```

И перед этим ,если используешь conntrack, эстаблишед релатед в ацепт.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но извини, немного слаб в этом. Я сделал JUMP таким образом, это не тоже самое?

**#создаю цепочку в Iptables:**
`iptables -N RULE_128`

**#создаю правило JUMP на переход если совпала подсеть до цепочки:**
`iptables -A INPUT -s 128.0.0.0/3 -j RULE_128`

**#создаю правило в цепочке на проверку подсетей в списке IPSET:**
`iptables -A RULE_128 --match block128 -j DROP`

Comment: С мобилки писал, опечатался много  наверное) главное смысл дошел) работает лучше?

Comment: Как оказалось, проблема была не в iptables (те мои правила работали тоже отлично), а в моей глупости. У моего Java приложения был один обработчик, про который я забыл, который запрашивал некоторые данные на другом постороннем сервере при коннекте. Я его случайно заблокировал, и эта задержка в 10 секунд была из за этого) Происходил таймаут. Понял я это, когда начал удалять по одной таблице, и в один момент обнаружил что проблема решилась. Хочется провалиться под землю) Спасибо тебе большое за то что откликнулся, по твоему совету разбил всё на цепочки, думаю так в любом случае будет лучше

Comment: С цепочками не переусердствуй;)